# Why doesn't my Minecraft skin change to my new personalized one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have created a nice looking Argonian with the Lich Kings Armor on it along with the Deadric Helmet from Skyrim. What I want to know is why it won't change the skin I choose to upload to Minecraft.net?

I gave it plenty of time. Restarting my computer didn't do a thing, restarting Minecraft didn't do anything and even resubmitting my skin to Minecraft.net multiple times didn't do squat.

Anyone out there have any solutions as to why this could be happening? The skin I choose is much better than this alex skin. My appologies if this has been asked already but I've already Googled the information and none of the search terms I've used helped me glean anything from what the problem is besides it being a change in the website.

Answer (score 3):

The Mojang servers have been experiencing issues today and Mojang has acknowledged this and is working/has worked on a fix

See https://www.twitter.com/MojangStatus for updates from Mojang.

See http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus for a live status update
Login: user authentication before launch, if this is down you can only play in offline mode. If you are on an online-mode server and you notice an abnormal decrease in players, check the status website. If login services are down, do not close your game as you will be unable to launch it in online-mode until the services are online again.
Session: Server session authentication, if this is down, online-mode servers will not be able to validate your game session and you will be unable to join. If you are on an online-mode server and you notice an abnormal decrease in players, check the status website; if session services are down do not disconnect from the server if you plan on playing again soon (next few minutes), as you will not be able to. 
Website: minecraft.net , if this is down you will be unable to access the game's website.
Textures: Skins and resource downloads, if this is down all players whose skins have not been downloaded by the current game session will show as a default skin (steve or alex), and launchers will be unable to download game resources (sounds, textures, etc)
Realms: Minecraft Realms, if this is down you will be unable to join Realms services.

Answer (score -3):

Nevermind I just got my answer:

It appears the Multiplayer Service is down for maintenance.

Comment: If caucow's answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark under the vote count :)